# create switching blinker on the BASCOM

Tags: microcontroller, avr, basic

I want to create a switching blinker in `BASCOM`. I wrote this code for this:

```basic
$regfile = "m16def.dat"
$crystal = 1000000

Config Portc = &B11111111
Config Portd.0 = 0
Portd.0 = 1
Portc = &H00

Do
If Portd.0 = 1 Then
   Portc = &B11000011
   Waitms 500
   Portc = &H00
   Waitms 500
Else
   Portc = &B00111100
   Waitms 500
   Portc = &H00
   Waitms 500
End If
Loop
```

but the result is this in `proteus`:
[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67280/difference-between-reading-port-and-pin) then I changed `If Portd.0 = 1 Then` to `If Pin = 1 Then` and it works. I do not exactly why my first command didn't work!

Comment: `Portd` is _output_ register for `AVR` ports and pull-up control register if port line configured as input.  Assignment `Portd.0 = 1` enables the pull-up but conditional `If Portd.0 = 1` checks the same bit in _output register_ while `Pind` is register for reading actual pin state.